# REST API using play-authenticate on Play 2.0 Java

Tags: rest, authentication, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I am planning to replace existing custom authentication with play-authenticate. The REST API returns a token back to the client after successful login and all the subsequent requests add that token as a query parameter.

Looking at the play-authenticate [code](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/code/app/com/feth/play/module/pa/PlayAuthenticate.java#L231), user details seem to be stored in the Play Session.

However, I am not sure if the client will use cookies at all. The old version compares the token to the stored value in order to authenticate each request. Obviously I can extend the PlayAuthenticate and override getUser etc methods. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Meanwhile, the client side agreed with the cookie approach so this isn't urgent anymore...